# Angular JS $httpProvider interceptor -- run with no response body?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm using interceptors to keep a running count of all $http requests; incrementing whenever a request starts, and decrementing whenever a response comes back.  The point of doing this is to allow me to show a busy spinner when any response has not yet come back without having to write the same code over and over again.

The code doing the heavy lifting is here (I've truncated the other interceptors which aren't really relevant here):

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$injector', function($q, $injector)
  {
    return {
      'request': function(config)
        {
          httpMonitorServiceProvider.activeHttpCalls++;
          return config;
        },
      'response': function(data)
        {
          httpMonitorServiceProvider.activeHttpCalls--;
          return data;
        }
    }
  }
```

This code works great for the most part, but some of the REST endpoints I have just return an HTTP OK status code without a response body (for POSTed "save" calls and the like where there's no need to return anything).  **When there's no response body the response interceptor never seems to be hit**, so the counter never goes back down.  If I modify the endpoints to return `{}` it does work.

Is there a way to intercept the responses that have no body?  I can modify the REST endpoints but I consider it less than ideal to have to return empty objects everywhere to hack around this issue.

Comment: personally I want a response for every request, relying solely on request status isn't foolproof

Comment: @charlietfl If I issue a request that says "delete record #500," let's say, what meaningful information would the response have that the request status didn't?

Comment: Can you check your network tab in developer's console for the request whose response body is empty? See if the status shows 'pending'

Comment: @Seram I have verified that the request is not pending.  That's not the issue.

Comment: I've just added your interceptor in my code and tested. The response has 200 Ok with no response body. I'm not getting any problem. it's goes inside the response function inside the interceptor